# Matrix values increasing after SVD, singular value decomposition

Tags: java, image, image-processing, svd

I am trying to learn SVD for image processing... like compression.

My approach: get image as BufferedImage using ImageIO... get RGB values and use them to get the equivalent grayscale value (which lies within 0-255) and store it in a `double[][]` array. And use that array in SVD to compress it.

I am getting my USV matrices correctly... hope so.
I get from U from AATranspose (AAT), and V from ATA.

Let me give an example

A is my original matrix.

```
A = 7.0     3.0     2.0
    9.0     7.0     5.0
    9.0     8.0     7.0
    5.0     3.0     6.0

U = -0.34598    -0.65267    -0.59969    -0.30771
    -0.57482    -0.27634     0.26045     0.72484
    -0.64327     0.21214     0.44200    -0.58808
    -0.36889     0.67280    -0.61415     0.18463

S = 21.57942    0.00000    0.00000
     0.00000    3.35324    0.00000
     0.00000    0.00000    2.02097
     0.00000    0.00000    0.00000

VT = -0.70573    -0.52432    -0.47649
     -0.53158    -0.05275     0.84536
     -0.46838     0.84989    -0.24149
```

So now I have to do outer product expansion, leaving out a few terms for compression. Lets call the truncated terms `k`.

When I let k = 1, and do outer product expansion with the singular values, this is what I get as my new matrix

```
B = 6.43235    4.03003    1.70732
    9.24653    6.55266    5.12711
    9.41838    7.24083    7.21571
    4.41866    4.05485    5.70027
```

As you can see, some values in B (which I think should be my final matrix after SVD) are greater than my original matrix.

`A` is just a test matrix. I would later try to compress a grayscale image, and there the values have to be 0-255. Anything > 255 wouldn't help me.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: `k` is the number of terms which I would be truncating. So when I say `k = 1`, the matrix I would be reconstructing would be:

```
A = u1 * S11 * vt1 + u2 * S22 + vt2
```

here u1 and u2 are column 1 and 2 of U, and vt1 and vt2 are row 1 and 2 of V.

Answer (score 1):

I actually asked [a question](https://www.kaggle.com/forums/f/15/kaggle-forum/t/16814/using-svd-for-noise-reduction) like this very recently on Kaggle. Hopefully it will be relevant to your computer vision question... One thing I don't understand, though, is how you're reconstructing `A'` after the truncation of `S`. From my understanding, when your `k=1`, the truncated diagonal matrix will look like this:

```
21.57942    0.00000    0.00000
0.00000     0.00000    0.00000
0.00000     0.00000    0.00000
0.00000     0.00000    0.00000
```

And `A'`, the approximation of what `A` may be without the more errant, low-energy singular values, can be reconstructed via `A' = US'Vt`. Here's my result for `A'`:

```
5.268951 3.914582 3.557461
8.753958 6.503777 5.910449
9.796523 7.278353 6.614362
5.617932 4.173858 3.793084
```

Why there are some values that are higher than the original `A` matrix makes sense when you consider that both `U` and `Vt` have negative values that are now being zeroed-out when you multiply by the new `S` matrix.

Edit with an additional resource: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590114/importance-of-pca-or-svd-in-machine-learning) out as well.

Comment: `k` is the number of terms which I am removing, `k` isn't the number of terms which I would be using. But I figured something out... I can truncate only the vectors from `U` and `VT` which correspond to zero singular value in `S`. If I go on to truncate a non-zero singular value, I get the problem which I am talking about in the question.

Comment: I still don't understand why this is a "problem." Values in the approximation matrix are allowed to be greater than the original matrix, as you will undoubtedly be removing some negative terms from the `V` and `U` matrices. This guy has a good tutorial on the basic intuition of SVD (remember, there are different use cases): http://matpalm.com/lsa_via_svd/eg1.html

Comment: If you aren't interested in the noise removal use case, you may be more interested in the use case presented in the answer in that Kaggle link I included in the answer, re: the `V` matrix truncation for the "mixing matrix."